# Flask Ajax call getting refreshed after data received to web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post, jsonify

I'm doing a flask project which get a data from a form(only one input) and using ajax POST request I posted it to server and return data on same page. In return I saw that returned data were received to the web page but it get refreshed automatically. I cannot figure out whats happening here.
This is my relevant codes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
        var userID=$("#userID").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/maturity',
            type:"POST",
            data:{userID:userID}
            }).done(function(data){
                 percentageval=data.id;
                 console.log(data.id);

            });
        });
 });
```

```
stack_overflow = Blueprint('stack_overflow', __name__)

@stack_overflow.route("/maturity", methods=["POST"])
def maturity():    
    data=request.form["userID"]
    print(data)
    id=46
    return jsonify({"id":46})
```

Here I created a maturity root to get POST data and return required values. This is default root I'm working with and after ajax call page refresh again to this page.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/stack_overflow
```

I've check that data has received to server and from `jasonify` data has returned to web page but problem was page refreshed again after that. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the following code within the form?

```
<button type="submit">Click Me</button>
```

Then change the type of the button.

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Maybe you should use the 'submit'-event instead of the 'click'-event.